# общий вопрос по Hadoop и MapReduce (простите)

Tags: hadoop, map-reduce

Появилась необходимость архитектурного совета по вопросу вычислений через MapReduce.

Вкратце:

Есть набор key-value данных объемом порядка 100 ГБ, нужно быстро (в идеале – почти на лету) агрегировать данные (простые математические операции).

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тем требованиями которые вы описали колоночная БД для этой задачи лучше подходит. Она как раз создана для того чтобы агрегировать данные + так как каждая колонка это по сути индекс фильтрация из коробки оптимизирована.

Если же у вас выбора по хранению данных нет, то да, обычный map-reduce и с добавлением вычислительных мощностей для "реалтайм" разрешения запросов:)

Comment: +1 колоночная бд тут то что нужно